# How To Set Environment Variable and Run Command Using ZX Process Promise

Tags: google-zx

I want to run something like the following but when I try I get the following error.

```js
const p = $`FOO=BAR && echo $FOO`
    
await p
```

`/usr/bin/bash: line 1: FOO=BAR && echo $FOO: command not found`